# Настроить в docker nginx 301 редиректы для всех index.html

Tags: nginx, redirect

У меня статический сайт в ngnix контейнере docker.
Сайт имеет структуру вида http://site.ru/, http://site.ru/about/
В каждой папке лежит свой index.html
Т. е. все страницы могут открываться по двум адресам, например, http://site.ru/about/ и http://site.ru/about/index.html - это полные дубли. Я хочу сделать для всех index.html 301й редирект. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^(.*/)index.html$) {
    return 301 $1;
}
```

Вот решение.